# How to compute the Topological Overlap Measure [TOM] for a weighted adjacency matrix in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, r, statistics, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to calculate the weighted topological overlap for an adjacency matrix but I cannot figure out how to do it correctly using `numpy`.  The `R` function that does the correct implementation is from `WGCNA` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WGCNA/versions/1.67/topics/TOMsimilarity).  The formula for computing this **(I THINK)** is detailed in [equation 4](http://dibernardo.tigem.it/files/papers/2008/zhangbin-statappsgeneticsmolbio.pdf) which I believe is correctly reproduced below.

[image]

**Does anyone know how to implement this correctly so it reflects the WGCNA version?**

Yes, I know about `rpy2` but I'm trying to go lightweight on this if possible.

For starters, my diagonal is not `1` and the values have no consistent error from the original (e.g. not all off by `x`).

When I computed this in `R`, I used the following:

```
> library(WGCNA, quiet=TRUE)
> df_adj = read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/sbAZQsE6", row.names=1, header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
> df_tom = TOMsimilarity(as.matrix(df_adj), TOMType="unsigned", TOMDenom="min")
# ..connectivity..
# ..matrix multiplication (system BLAS)..
# ..normalization..
# ..done.
# I've uploaded it to this url: https://pastebin.com/raw/HT2gBaZC
```

I'm not sure where my code is incorrect.  The source code for the `R` version is [here](https://github.com/cran/WGCNA/blob/master/src/networkFunctions.c) but it's using `C` backend scripts? which is very difficult for me interpret.

Here is my implementation in `Python` :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

def get_iris_data():
    iris = load_iris()
    # Iris dataset
    X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data,
                     index = [*map(lambda x:f"iris_{x}", range(150))],
                     columns = [*map(lambda x: x.split(" (cm)")[0].replace(" ","_"), iris.feature_names)])

    y = pd.Series(iris.target,
                           index = X.index,
                           name = "Species")
    return X, y

# Get data
X, y = get_iris_data()

# Create an adjacency network
# df_adj = np.abs(X.T.corr()) # I've uploaded this part to this url: https://pastebin.com/raw/sbAZQsE6
df_adj = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/sbAZQsE6", sep="\t", index_col=0)
A_adj = df_adj.values

# Correct TOM from WGCNA for the A_adj
# See above for code
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WGCNA/versions/1.67/topics/TOMsimilarity
df_tom__wgcna = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/HT2gBaZC", sep="\t", index_col=0)

# My attempt
A = A_adj.copy()
dimensions = A.shape
assert dimensions[0] == dimensions[1]
d = dimensions[0]

# np.fill_diagonal(A, 0)

# Equation (4) from http://dibernardo.tigem.it/files/papers/2008/zhangbin-statappsgeneticsmolbio.pdf
A_tom = np.zeros_like(A)
for i in range(d):
    a_iu = A[i]
    k_i = a_iu.sum()
    for j in range(i+1, d):
        a_ju = A[:,j]
        k_j = a_ju.sum()
        l_ij = np.dot(a_iu, a_ju)
        a_ij = A[i,j]
        numerator = l_ij + a_ij
        denominator = min(k_i, k_j) + 1 - a_ij
        w_ij = numerator/denominator
        A_tom[i,j] = w_ij
A_tom = (A_tom + A_tom.T)
```

There is a package called `GTOM` (https://github.com/benmaier/gtom) but it is not for weighted adjacencies.  [The author of GTOM also took a look at this problem](https://github.com/benmaier/GTOM/issues/3) (which a much more sophisticated/efficient `NumPy` implementation but it's still not producing the expected results).

**Does anyone know how to reproduce the WGCNA implementation?**

EDIT: 2019.06.20
I've adapted some of the code from @scleronomic and [@benmaier](https://github.com/benmaier) with credits in the doc string.  The function is available in [soothsayer](https://github.com/jolespin/soothsayer) from `v2016.06` and on.  Hopefully this will allow people to use topological overlap in Python easier instead of only being able to use R.

[image]

https://github.com/jolespin/soothsayer/blob/master/soothsayer/networks/networks.py

```
import numpy as np
import soothsayer as sy
df_adj = sy.io.read_dataframe("https://pastebin.com/raw/sbAZQsE6")
df_tom = sy.networks.topological_overlap_measure(df_adj)
df_tom__wgcna = sy.io.read_dataframe("https://pastebin.com/raw/HT2gBaZC")
np.allclose(df_tom, df_tom__wgcna)
# True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's look at the parts of the equation for the case of a binary adjacency matrix `a_ij`:

- `a_ij`: indicates if node `i` is connected to node `j`
- `k_i`: count of the neighbors of node `i` (connectivity)
- `l_ij`: count of the common neighbors of node `i` and node `j`

so `w_ij` measures how many of the neighbors of the node with the lower connectivity are also neighbors of the other node (ie. `w_ij` measures "their relative inter-connectedness").

My guess is that they define the diagonal of *A* to be zero instead of one.
With this assumption I can reproduce the values of *WGCNA*.

```py
A[range(d), range(d)] = 0  # Assumption
L = A @ A  # Could be done smarter by using the symmetry
K = A.sum(axis=1)

A_tom = np.zeros_like(A)
for i in range(d):
    for j in range(i+1, d):  
        numerator = L[i, j] + A[i, j]
        denominator = min(K[i], K[j]) + 1 - A[i, j]
        A_tom[i, j] = numerator / denominator
    
A_tom += A_tom.T
A_tom[range(d), range(d)] = 1  # Set diagonal to 1 by default

A_tom__wgcna = np.array(pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/HT2gBaZC", 
                        sep="\t", index_col=0))
print(np.allclose(A_tom, A_tom__wgcna))
```

An intuition why the diagonal of A should be zero instead of one can be seen for a simple example with a binary A:

```
 Graph      Case Zero    Case One
   B          A B C D      A B C D  
 /   \      A 0 1 1 1    A 1 1 1 1  
A-----D     B 1 0 0 1    B 1 1 0 1  
 \   /      C 1 0 0 1    C 1 0 1 1  
   C        D 1 1 1 0    D 1 1 1 1
```

The given description of equation 4 explains:

> Note that `w_ij = 1` if the node with fewer connections satisfies two conditions:
>
> - (a) all of its neighbors are also neighbors of the other node and
> - (b) it is connected to the other node.
>
> In contrast, `w_ij = 0` if `i` and `j` are un-connected and the two nodes do not share any neighbors.

So the connection between A-D should fulfill this criterion and be `w_14=1`.

- Case Zero Diagonal:  [image]
- Case One Diagonal:   [image]

What is still missing when applying the formula is that the diagonal values don't match. I set them to one by default. What is the inter-connectedness of a node with itself anyway? A value different than one (or zero, depending on definition) doesn't make sense to me.
Neither *Case Zero* nor *Case One* result in `w_ii=1` in the simple example.
In *Case Zero* it would be necessary that `k_i+1 == l_ii`, and in *Case One* it would be necessary that `k_i == l_ii+1`, which both seems wrong to me.

So to summarize I would set the diagonal of the adjacency matrix to `zero`, use the given equation and set the diagonal of the result to `one` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the help on figuring this out!  I was doing the `L` matrix incorrectly ha ah man.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to increase the speed using broadcasting on this function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090539/how-can-i-use-broadcasting-with-numpy-to-speed-up-this-correlation-calculation

Answer (score 1):

Given adjacency matrix A, its possible to calculate the TOM matrix W without the use of for loops, which speeds up the process tremendously

```
L = np.dot(A,A)
k = np.sum(A,axis=0); d = len(k); tile = np.tile(k,(d,1))
K = np.min(np.stack((tile,tile.T),axis=2),axis=2)
W = (L + A)/(K + 1 - A); np.fill_diagonal(W, 1)
```