# How can I use broadcasting with NumPy to speed up this correlation calculation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to take advantage of [NumPy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and backend array computations to significantly speed up this function.  Unfortunately, it doesn't scale so well so I'm hoping to greatly improve the performance of this.  Right now the code isn't properly utilizing broadcasting for the computations.

I'm using [WGCNA's bicor function](https://rdrr.io/cran/WGCNA/man/bicor.html) as a gold standard as this is the fastest implementation I know of at the moment.  The Python version outputs the same results as the R function.

```
# ==============================================================================
# Imports
# ==============================================================================
# Built-ins
import os, sys, time, multiprocessing
# 3rd party
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# ==============================================================================
# R Imports
# ==============================================================================
from rpy2 import robjects, rinterface
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
R = robjects.r
NULL = robjects.rinterface.NULL
rinterface.set_writeconsole_regular(None)
WGCNA = importr("WGCNA")

# Python
def _biweight_midcorrelation(a, b):
    a_median = np.median(a)
    b_median = np.median(b)

    # Median absolute deviation
    a_mad = np.median(np.abs(a - a_median))
    b_mad = np.median(np.abs(b - b_median))

    u = (a - a_median) / (9 * a_mad)
    v = (b - b_median) / (9 * b_mad)

    w_a = np.square(1 - np.square(u)) * ((1 - np.abs(u)) > 0)
    w_b = np.square(1 - np.square(v)) * ((1 - np.abs(v)) > 0)

    a_item = (a - a_median) * w_a
    b_item = (b - b_median) * w_b

    return (a_item * b_item).sum() / (
        np.sqrt(np.square(a_item).sum()) *
        np.sqrt(np.square(b_item).sum()))

def biweight_midcorrelation(X):
    return X.corr(method=_biweight_midcorrelation)
# # OLD IMPLEMENTATION
# def biweight_midcorrelation(X):
#     median = X.median()
#     mad = (X - median).abs().median()
#     U = (X - median) / (9 * mad)
#     adjacency = np.square(1 - np.square(U)) * ((1 - U.abs()) > 0)
#     estimator = (X - median) * adjacency

#     bicor_matrix = np.empty((X.shape[1], X.shape[1]), dtype=float)

#     for i, ac in enumerate(estimator):
#         for j, bc in enumerate(estimator):
#             a = estimator[ac]
#             b = estimator[bc]

#             c = (a * b).sum() / (
#                 np.sqrt(np.square(a).sum()) * np.sqrt(np.square(b).sum()))
#             bicor_matrix[i, j] = c
#             bicor_matrix[j, i] = c
#     return pd.DataFrame(bicor_matrix, index=X.columns, columns=X.columns)

# R
def biweight_midcorrelation_r_wrapper(X, n_jobs=-1, r_package=None):
    """
    WGCNA: bicor
        function (x, y = NULL, robustX = TRUE, robustY = TRUE, use = "all.obs",
                   maxPOutliers = 1, qu <...> dian absolute deviation, or zero variance."))
    """
    if r_package is None:
        r_package = importr("WGCNA")
    if n_jobs == -1:
        n_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    labels = X.columns
    r_df_sim = r_package.bicor(pandas2ri.py2ri(X), nThreads=n_jobs)
    df_bicor = pd.DataFrame(pandas2ri.ri2py(r_df_sim), index=labels, columns=labels)
    return df_bicor

# X.shape = (150,4)
X = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': {'iris_0': 5.1, 'iris_1': 4.9, 'iris_2': 4.7, 'iris_3': 4.6, 'iris_4': 5.0, 'iris_5': 5.4, 'iris_6': 4.6, 'iris_7': 5.0, 'iris_8': 4.4, 'iris_9': 4.9, 'iris_10': 5.4, 'iris_11': 4.8, 'iris_12': 4.8, 'iris_13': 4.3, 'iris_14': 5.8, 'iris_15': 5.7, 'iris_16': 5.4, 'iris_17': 5.1, 'iris_18': 5.7, 'iris_19': 5.1, 'iris_20': 5.4, 'iris_21': 5.1, 'iris_22': 4.6, 'iris_23': 5.1, 'iris_24': 4.8, 'iris_25': 5.0, 'iris_26': 5.0, 'iris_27': 5.2, 'iris_28': 5.2, 'iris_29': 4.7, 'iris_30': 4.8, 'iris_31': 5.4, 'iris_32': 5.2, 'iris_33': 5.5, 'iris_34': 4.9, 'iris_35': 5.0, 'iris_36': 5.5, 'iris_37': 4.9, 'iris_38': 4.4, 'iris_39': 5.1, 'iris_40': 5.0, 'iris_41': 4.5, 'iris_42': 4.4, 'iris_43': 5.0, 'iris_44': 5.1, 'iris_45': 4.8, 'iris_46': 5.1, 'iris_47': 4.6, 'iris_48': 5.3, 'iris_49': 5.0, 'iris_50': 7.0, 'iris_51': 6.4, 'iris_52': 6.9, 'iris_53': 5.5, 'iris_54': 6.5, 'iris_55': 5.7, 'iris_56': 6.3, 'iris_57': 4.9, 'iris_58': 6.6, 'iris_59': 5.2, 'iris_60': 5.0, 'iris_61': 5.9, 'iris_62': 6.0, 'iris_63': 6.1, 'iris_64': 5.6, 'iris_65': 6.7, 'iris_66': 5.6, 'iris_67': 5.8, 'iris_68': 6.2, 'iris_69': 5.6, 'iris_70': 5.9, 'iris_71': 6.1, 'iris_72': 6.3, 'iris_73': 6.1, 'iris_74': 6.4, 'iris_75': 6.6, 'iris_76': 6.8, 'iris_77': 6.7, 'iris_78': 6.0, 'iris_79': 5.7, 'iris_80': 5.5, 'iris_81': 5.5, 'iris_82': 5.8, 'iris_83': 6.0, 'iris_84': 5.4, 'iris_85': 6.0, 'iris_86': 6.7, 'iris_87': 6.3, 'iris_88': 5.6, 'iris_89': 5.5, 'iris_90': 5.5, 'iris_91': 6.1, 'iris_92': 5.8, 'iris_93': 5.0, 'iris_94': 5.6, 'iris_95': 5.7, 'iris_96': 5.7, 'iris_97': 6.2, 'iris_98': 5.1, 'iris_99': 5.7, 'iris_100': 6.3, 'iris_101': 5.8, 'iris_102': 7.1, 'iris_103': 6.3, 'iris_104': 6.5, 'iris_105': 7.6, 'iris_106': 4.9, 'iris_107': 7.3, 'iris_108': 6.7, 'iris_109': 7.2, 'iris_110': 6.5, 'iris_111': 6.4, 'iris_112': 6.8, 'iris_113': 5.7, 'iris_114': 5.8, 'iris_115': 6.4, 'iris_116': 6.5, 'iris_117': 7.7, 'iris_118': 7.7, 'iris_119': 6.0, 'iris_120': 6.9, 'iris_121': 5.6, 'iris_122': 7.7, 'iris_123': 6.3, 'iris_124': 6.7, 'iris_125': 7.2, 'iris_126': 6.2, 'iris_127': 6.1, 'iris_128': 6.4, 'iris_129': 7.2, 'iris_130': 7.4, 'iris_131': 7.9, 'iris_132': 6.4, 'iris_133': 6.3, 'iris_134': 6.1, 'iris_135': 7.7, 'iris_136': 6.3, 'iris_137': 6.4, 'iris_138': 6.0, 'iris_139': 6.9, 'iris_140': 6.7, 'iris_141': 6.9, 'iris_142': 5.8, 'iris_143': 6.8, 'iris_144': 6.7, 'iris_145': 6.7, 'iris_146': 6.3, 'iris_147': 6.5, 'iris_148': 6.2, 'iris_149': 5.9}, 'sepal_width': {'iris_0': 3.5, 'iris_1': 3.0, 'iris_2': 3.2, 'iris_3': 3.1, 'iris_4': 3.6, 'iris_5': 3.9, 'iris_6': 3.4, 'iris_7': 3.4, 'iris_8': 2.9, 'iris_9': 3.1, 'iris_10': 3.7, 'iris_11': 3.4, 'iris_12': 3.0, 'iris_13': 3.0, 'iris_14': 4.0, 'iris_15': 4.4, 'iris_16': 3.9, 'iris_17': 3.5, 'iris_18': 3.8, 'iris_19': 3.8, 'iris_20': 3.4, 'iris_21': 3.7, 'iris_22': 3.6, 'iris_23': 3.3, 'iris_24': 3.4, 'iris_25': 3.0, 'iris_26': 3.4, 'iris_27': 3.5, 'iris_28': 3.4, 'iris_29': 3.2, 'iris_30': 3.1, 'iris_31': 3.4, 'iris_32': 4.1, 'iris_33': 4.2, 'iris_34': 3.1, 'iris_35': 3.2, 'iris_36': 3.5, 'iris_37': 3.6, 'iris_38': 3.0, 'iris_39': 3.4, 'iris_40': 3.5, 'iris_41': 2.3, 'iris_42': 3.2, 'iris_43': 3.5, 'iris_44': 3.8, 'iris_45': 3.0, 'iris_46': 3.8, 'iris_47': 3.2, 'iris_48': 3.7, 'iris_49': 3.3, 'iris_50': 3.2, 'iris_51': 3.2, 'iris_52': 3.1, 'iris_53': 2.3, 'iris_54': 2.8, 'iris_55': 2.8, 'iris_56': 3.3, 'iris_57': 2.4, 'iris_58': 2.9, 'iris_59': 2.7, 'iris_60': 2.0, 'iris_61': 3.0, 'iris_62': 2.2, 'iris_63': 2.9, 'iris_64': 2.9, 'iris_65': 3.1, 'iris_66': 3.0, 'iris_67': 2.7, 'iris_68': 2.2, 'iris_69': 2.5, 'iris_70': 3.2, 'iris_71': 2.8, 'iris_72': 2.5, 'iris_73': 2.8, 'iris_74': 2.9, 'iris_75': 3.0, 'iris_76': 2.8, 'iris_77': 3.0, 'iris_78': 2.9, 'iris_79': 2.6, 'iris_80': 2.4, 'iris_81': 2.4, 'iris_82': 2.7, 'iris_83': 2.7, 'iris_84': 3.0, 'iris_85': 3.4, 'iris_86': 3.1, 'iris_87': 2.3, 'iris_88': 3.0, 'iris_89': 2.5, 'iris_90': 2.6, 'iris_91': 3.0, 'iris_92': 2.6, 'iris_93': 2.3, 'iris_94': 2.7, 'iris_95': 3.0, 'iris_96': 2.9, 'iris_97': 2.9, 'iris_98': 2.5, 'iris_99': 2.8, 'iris_100': 3.3, 'iris_101': 2.7, 'iris_102': 3.0, 'iris_103': 2.9, 'iris_104': 3.0, 'iris_105': 3.0, 'iris_106': 2.5, 'iris_107': 2.9, 'iris_108': 2.5, 'iris_109': 3.6, 'iris_110': 3.2, 'iris_111': 2.7, 'iris_112': 3.0, 'iris_113': 2.5, 'iris_114': 2.8, 'iris_115': 3.2, 'iris_116': 3.0, 'iris_117': 3.8, 'iris_118': 2.6, 'iris_119': 2.2, 'iris_120': 3.2, 'iris_121': 2.8, 'iris_122': 2.8, 'iris_123': 2.7, 'iris_124': 3.3, 'iris_125': 3.2, 'iris_126': 2.8, 'iris_127': 3.0, 'iris_128': 2.8, 'iris_129': 3.0, 'iris_130': 2.8, 'iris_131': 3.8, 'iris_132': 2.8, 'iris_133': 2.8, 'iris_134': 2.6, 'iris_135': 3.0, 'iris_136': 3.4, 'iris_137': 3.1, 'iris_138': 3.0, 'iris_139': 3.1, 'iris_140': 3.1, 'iris_141': 3.1, 'iris_142': 2.7, 'iris_143': 3.2, 'iris_144': 3.3, 'iris_145': 3.0, 'iris_146': 2.5, 'iris_147': 3.0, 'iris_148': 3.4, 'iris_149': 3.0}, 'petal_length': {'iris_0': 1.4, 'iris_1': 1.4, 'iris_2': 1.3, 'iris_3': 1.5, 'iris_4': 1.4, 'iris_5': 1.7, 'iris_6': 1.4, 'iris_7': 1.5, 'iris_8': 1.4, 'iris_9': 1.5, 'iris_10': 1.5, 'iris_11': 1.6, 'iris_12': 1.4, 'iris_13': 1.1, 'iris_14': 1.2, 'iris_15': 1.5, 'iris_16': 1.3, 'iris_17': 1.4, 'iris_18': 1.7, 'iris_19': 1.5, 'iris_20': 1.7, 'iris_21': 1.5, 'iris_22': 1.0, 'iris_23': 1.7, 'iris_24': 1.9, 'iris_25': 1.6, 'iris_26': 1.6, 'iris_27': 1.5, 'iris_28': 1.4, 'iris_29': 1.6, 'iris_30': 1.6, 'iris_31': 1.5, 'iris_32': 1.5, 'iris_33': 1.4, 'iris_34': 1.5, 'iris_35': 1.2, 'iris_36': 1.3, 'iris_37': 1.4, 'iris_38': 1.3, 'iris_39': 1.5, 'iris_40': 1.3, 'iris_41': 1.3, 'iris_42': 1.3, 'iris_43': 1.6, 'iris_44': 1.9, 'iris_45': 1.4, 'iris_46': 1.6, 'iris_47': 1.4, 'iris_48': 1.5, 'iris_49': 1.4, 'iris_50': 4.7, 'iris_51': 4.5, 'iris_52': 4.9, 'iris_53': 4.0, 'iris_54': 4.6, 'iris_55': 4.5, 'iris_56': 4.7, 'iris_57': 3.3, 'iris_58': 4.6, 'iris_59': 3.9, 'iris_60': 3.5, 'iris_61': 4.2, 'iris_62': 4.0, 'iris_63': 4.7, 'iris_64': 3.6, 'iris_65': 4.4, 'iris_66': 4.5, 'iris_67': 4.1, 'iris_68': 4.5, 'iris_69': 3.9, 'iris_70': 4.8, 'iris_71': 4.0, 'iris_72': 4.9, 'iris_73': 4.7, 'iris_74': 4.3, 'iris_75': 4.4, 'iris_76': 4.8, 'iris_77': 5.0, 'iris_78': 4.5, 'iris_79': 3.5, 'iris_80': 3.8, 'iris_81': 3.7, 'iris_82': 3.9, 'iris_83': 5.1, 'iris_84': 4.5, 'iris_85': 4.5, 'iris_86': 4.7, 'iris_87': 4.4, 'iris_88': 4.1, 'iris_89': 4.0, 'iris_90': 4.4, 'iris_91': 4.6, 'iris_92': 4.0, 'iris_93': 3.3, 'iris_94': 4.2, 'iris_95': 4.2, 'iris_96': 4.2, 'iris_97': 4.3, 'iris_98': 3.0, 'iris_99': 4.1, 'iris_100': 6.0, 'iris_101': 5.1, 'iris_102': 5.9, 'iris_103': 5.6, 'iris_104': 5.8, 'iris_105': 6.6, 'iris_106': 4.5, 'iris_107': 6.3, 'iris_108': 5.8, 'iris_109': 6.1, 'iris_110': 5.1, 'iris_111': 5.3, 'iris_112': 5.5, 'iris_113': 5.0, 'iris_114': 5.1, 'iris_115': 5.3, 'iris_116': 5.5, 'iris_117': 6.7, 'iris_118': 6.9, 'iris_119': 5.0, 'iris_120': 5.7, 'iris_121': 4.9, 'iris_122': 6.7, 'iris_123': 4.9, 'iris_124': 5.7, 'iris_125': 6.0, 'iris_126': 4.8, 'iris_127': 4.9, 'iris_128': 5.6, 'iris_129': 5.8, 'iris_130': 6.1, 'iris_131': 6.4, 'iris_132': 5.6, 'iris_133': 5.1, 'iris_134': 5.6, 'iris_135': 6.1, 'iris_136': 5.6, 'iris_137': 5.5, 'iris_138': 4.8, 'iris_139': 5.4, 'iris_140': 5.6, 'iris_141': 5.1, 'iris_142': 5.1, 'iris_143': 5.9, 'iris_144': 5.7, 'iris_145': 5.2, 'iris_146': 5.0, 'iris_147': 5.2, 'iris_148': 5.4, 'iris_149': 5.1}, 'petal_width': {'iris_0': 0.2, 'iris_1': 0.2, 'iris_2': 0.2, 'iris_3': 0.2, 'iris_4': 0.2, 'iris_5': 0.4, 'iris_6': 0.3, 'iris_7': 0.2, 'iris_8': 0.2, 'iris_9': 0.1, 'iris_10': 0.2, 'iris_11': 0.2, 'iris_12': 0.1, 'iris_13': 0.1, 'iris_14': 0.2, 'iris_15': 0.4, 'iris_16': 0.4, 'iris_17': 0.3, 'iris_18': 0.3, 'iris_19': 0.3, 'iris_20': 0.2, 'iris_21': 0.4, 'iris_22': 0.2, 'iris_23': 0.5, 'iris_24': 0.2, 'iris_25': 0.2, 'iris_26': 0.4, 'iris_27': 0.2, 'iris_28': 0.2, 'iris_29': 0.2, 'iris_30': 0.2, 'iris_31': 0.4, 'iris_32': 0.1, 'iris_33': 0.2, 'iris_34': 0.2, 'iris_35': 0.2, 'iris_36': 0.2, 'iris_37': 0.1, 'iris_38': 0.2, 'iris_39': 0.2, 'iris_40': 0.3, 'iris_41': 0.3, 'iris_42': 0.2, 'iris_43': 0.6, 'iris_44': 0.4, 'iris_45': 0.3, 'iris_46': 0.2, 'iris_47': 0.2, 'iris_48': 0.2, 'iris_49': 0.2, 'iris_50': 1.4, 'iris_51': 1.5, 'iris_52': 1.5, 'iris_53': 1.3, 'iris_54': 1.5, 'iris_55': 1.3, 'iris_56': 1.6, 'iris_57': 1.0, 'iris_58': 1.3, 'iris_59': 1.4, 'iris_60': 1.0, 'iris_61': 1.5, 'iris_62': 1.0, 'iris_63': 1.4, 'iris_64': 1.3, 'iris_65': 1.4, 'iris_66': 1.5, 'iris_67': 1.0, 'iris_68': 1.5, 'iris_69': 1.1, 'iris_70': 1.8, 'iris_71': 1.3, 'iris_72': 1.5, 'iris_73': 1.2, 'iris_74': 1.3, 'iris_75': 1.4, 'iris_76': 1.4, 'iris_77': 1.7, 'iris_78': 1.5, 'iris_79': 1.0, 'iris_80': 1.1, 'iris_81': 1.0, 'iris_82': 1.2, 'iris_83': 1.6, 'iris_84': 1.5, 'iris_85': 1.6, 'iris_86': 1.5, 'iris_87': 1.3, 'iris_88': 1.3, 'iris_89': 1.3, 'iris_90': 1.2, 'iris_91': 1.4, 'iris_92': 1.2, 'iris_93': 1.0, 'iris_94': 1.3, 'iris_95': 1.2, 'iris_96': 1.3, 'iris_97': 1.3, 'iris_98': 1.1, 'iris_99': 1.3, 'iris_100': 2.5, 'iris_101': 1.9, 'iris_102': 2.1, 'iris_103': 1.8, 'iris_104': 2.2, 'iris_105': 2.1, 'iris_106': 1.7, 'iris_107': 1.8, 'iris_108': 1.8, 'iris_109': 2.5, 'iris_110': 2.0, 'iris_111': 1.9, 'iris_112': 2.1, 'iris_113': 2.0, 'iris_114': 2.4, 'iris_115': 2.3, 'iris_116': 1.8, 'iris_117': 2.2, 'iris_118': 2.3, 'iris_119': 1.5, 'iris_120': 2.3, 'iris_121': 2.0, 'iris_122': 2.0, 'iris_123': 1.8, 'iris_124': 2.1, 'iris_125': 1.8, 'iris_126': 1.8, 'iris_127': 1.8, 'iris_128': 2.1, 'iris_129': 1.6, 'iris_130': 1.9, 'iris_131': 2.0, 'iris_132': 2.2, 'iris_133': 1.5, 'iris_134': 1.4, 'iris_135': 2.3, 'iris_136': 2.4, 'iris_137': 1.8, 'iris_138': 1.8, 'iris_139': 2.1, 'iris_140': 2.4, 'iris_141': 2.3, 'iris_142': 1.9, 'iris_143': 2.3, 'iris_144': 2.5, 'iris_145': 2.3, 'iris_146': 1.9, 'iris_147': 2.0, 'iris_148': 2.3, 'iris_149': 1.8}})

# Python computation
start_time = time.time()
df_bicor__python = biweight_midcorrelation(X)

# R computation
df_bicor__r = biweight_midcorrelation_r_wrapper(X)

np.allclose(df_bicor__python, df_bicor__r)
```

Comment: That `estimator[ac]` looks wrong.  `ac` is an element of `estimator`.  `i` is the element index.

Comment: @hpaulj I compared it with the R version above for a gold standard.

Comment: @hpaulj I realized that I added the older implementation.  I've added a faster version but it still doesn't properly utilize broadcasting for 2D.

Comment: Explain why you think `broadcasting` is relevant or needed.  There's no loop inside `_biweight_midcorrelation`.  Give it two Series and you get the corresponding value from `corr`.  I think you should show the result of the `X.corr`, and demonstrate how it arrives at that.  I was able to run it (because you gave a working `df` definition), but I think you should provide enough output so others can see what's happening without running it.

Comment: Here is an example of someone using broadcoasting to speed up a pairwise function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574729/how-to-compute-the-topological-overlap-measure-tom-for-a-weighted-adjacency-ma  I feel like there is a similar way to do this with this particular correlation function.

Comment: How slow is your Python code compared to the "gold standard" R implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Summary

One could write this computation approx. one order of magnitude faster (for the input you specified) with:

```
import numpy as np


def biweight_midcorrelation(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    arr = arr - np.median(arr, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    v = 1 - (arr / (9 * np.median(np.abs(arr), axis=0, keepdims=True))) ** 2
    arr = arr * v ** 2 * (v > 0)
    norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(arr ** 2, axis=0))
    return np.einsum('mi,mj->ij', arr, arr) / norms[:, None] / norms[None, :]
```

to be bridged to a Pandas dataframe by:

```
import pandas as pd


def corr_np2pd(df, func):
    return pd.DataFrame(func(np.array(df)), index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
```

whose usage is:

```
corr_df = corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation)
```

This could be made even faster by implementing the last computation with Numba.

---

## Introduction

I am not quite sure why you expect broadcasting to be of help in the current code.
Did you perhaps mean vectorizing?
Anyway, I believe that it is possible to write faster code, and a vectorized version of your "old" approach would outperform your current approach.
This could be made even faster using Numba.

---

There are two practical approaches to your problem:

1. to manually compute the correlation matrix
2. to generate a correlation function to be passed to `pd.DataFrame.corr()`

When doing (1), an explicit looping may not be avoidable without computing unnecessary parts of the correlation matrix.

When doing (2), it will be necessary to compute the auxiliary value of the computation for each (symmetric) pair of the 1D inputs ([`2 * comb(n, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb) times), as opposed to computing the auxiliary values only once for each of the 1D inputs (`n` times). For example, for the input specified in the question, one would need to perform `n == 4` pre-computations, but, if done in pairwise fashion, this number becomes `2 * comb(4, 2) == 12`.

Let us see how can we push the performances in both cases.

## Manually Computing the Correlation Matrix

---

Let us first define a function to serve as a Pandas-to-NumPy bridge:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def corr_np2pd(df, func):
    return pd.DataFrame(func(np.array(df)), index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
```

---

The function with explicit looping that is now in the comments belongs to this category and it is reported below as `biweight_midcorrelation_pd_OP()`:

```
def biweight_midcorrelation_pd_OP(X):
    median = X.median()
    mad = (X - median).abs().median()
    U = (X - median) / (9 * mad)
    adjacency = np.square(1 - np.square(U)) * ((1 - U.abs()) > 0)
    estimator = (X - median) * adjacency
    bicor_matrix = np.empty((X.shape[1], X.shape[1]), dtype=float)
    for i, ac in enumerate(estimator):
        for j, bc in enumerate(estimator):
            a = estimator[ac]
            b = estimator[bc]
            c = (a * b).sum() / (
                np.sqrt(np.square(a).sum()) * np.sqrt(np.square(b).sum()))
            bicor_matrix[i, j] = c
            bicor_matrix[j, i] = c
    return pd.DataFrame(bicor_matrix, index=X.columns, columns=X.columns)
```

A slightly modified version of that, where the computation is done entirely in NumPy and which should be used with `corr_np2pd()`, reads:

```
def biweight_midcorrelation_OP(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    med = np.median(arr, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    mad = np.median(np.abs(arr - med), axis=0, keepdims=True)
    u = (arr - med) / (9 * mad)
    adj = ((1 - u ** 2) ** 2) * ((1 - np.abs(u)) > 0)
    est = (arr - med) * adj
    result = np.empty((m, m))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(m):
            a = est[:, i]
            b = est[:, j]
            c = (a * b).sum() / (
                np.sqrt(np.sum(a ** 2)) * np.sqrt(np.sum(b ** 2)))
            result[i, j] = result[j, i] = c
    return result
```

Now, this has some points of improvement:

- the intermediate computations can be reduced
- the final nested loop could be made more efficient

This last point could be improved with two ways:

- by only computing the symmetric indices once, resulting in `biweight_midcorrelation_np()`
- by writing it in vectorized form, resulting in `biweight_midcorrelation_npv()`

```
def biweight_midcorrelation_np(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    arr = arr - np.median(arr, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    v = 1 - (arr / (9 * np.median(np.abs(arr), axis=0, keepdims=True))) ** 2
    arr = arr * v ** 2 * (v > 0)
    norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(arr ** 2, axis=0))
    result = np.empty((m, m))
    np.fill_diagonal(result, 1.0)
    for i, j in zip(*np.triu_indices(m, 1)):
        result[i, j] = result[j, i] = \
            np.sum(arr[:, i] * arr[:, j]) / norms[i] / norms[j]
    return result
```

```
def biweight_midcorrelation_npv(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    arr = arr - np.median(arr, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    v = 1 - (arr / (9 * np.median(np.abs(arr), axis=0, keepdims=True))) ** 2
    arr = arr * v ** 2 * (v > 0)
    norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(arr ** 2, axis=0))
    return np.einsum('mi,mj->ij', arr, arr) / norms[:, None] / norms[None, :]
```

The first one will be fast as long as `m` is small, because of the explicit looping.
The second one will generally be fast, but it seems inefficient to compute some of the entries of the matrix twice.
To overcome both issues, one could rewrite the final loop with Numba:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def _biweight_midcorrelation_triu_nb(n, m, est, norms, result):
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(i + 1, m):
            x = 0
            for k in range(n):
                x += est[k, i] * est[k, j]
            result[i, j] = result[j, i] = x / norms[i] / norms[j]


def biweight_midcorrelation_nb(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    arr = arr - np.median(arr, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    v = 1 - (arr / (9 * np.median(np.abs(arr), axis=0, keepdims=True))) ** 2
    arr = arr * v ** 2 * (v > 0)
    norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(arr ** 2, axis=0))
    result = np.empty((m, m))
    np.fill_diagonal(result, 1.0)
    _biweight_midcorrelation_triu_nb(n, m, arr, norms, result)
    return result
```

## Pairwise Correlation Function

A slightly modified version of your now proposed approach belongs to this category:

```
def pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_OP(a, b):
    a_median = np.median(a)
    b_median = np.median(b)
    a_mad = np.median(np.abs(a - a_median))
    b_mad = np.median(np.abs(b - b_median))
    u_a = (a - a_median) / (9 * a_mad)
    u_b = (b - b_median) / (9 * b_mad)
    adj_a = (1 - u_a ** 2) ** 2 * ((1 - np.abs(u_a)) > 0)
    adj_b = (1 - u_b ** 2) ** 2 * ((1 - np.abs(u_b)) > 0)
    a = (a - a_median) * adj_a
    b = (b - b_median) * adj_b
    return np.sum(a * b) / (np.sqrt(np.sum(a ** 2)) * np.sqrt(np.sum(b ** 2)))
```

This may be written a bit more concisely, using similar simplifications as above, resuling in:

```
def pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_opt(a, b):
    a = a - np.median(a)
    b = b - np.median(b)
    v_a = 1 - (a / (9 * np.median(np.abs(a)))) ** 2
    v_b = 1 - (b / (9 * np.median(np.abs(b)))) ** 2
    a = a * v_a ** 2 * (v_a > 0)
    b = b * v_b ** 2 * (v_b > 0)
    return np.sum(a * b) / (np.sqrt(np.sum(a ** 2)) * np.sqrt(np.sum(b ** 2)))
```

The last operation is performing summation over `a` and `b` three times, but it could actually be done in a single loop, which could be again made fast with Numba:

```
@nb.jit
def pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_nb(a, b):
    n = a.size
    a = a - np.median(a)
    b = b - np.median(b)
    v_a = 1 - (a / (9 * np.median(np.abs(a)))) ** 2
    v_b = 1 - (b / (9 * np.median(np.abs(b)))) ** 2
    a = (v_a > 0) * a * v_a ** 2
    b = (v_b > 0) * b * v_b ** 2
    s_ab = s_aa = s_bb = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s_ab += a[i] * b[i]
        s_aa += a[i] * a[i]
        s_bb += b[i] * b[i]
    return s_ab / np.sqrt(s_aa) / np.sqrt(s_bb)
```

But there is no simple way of avoiding to perform the pre-computations [`2 * comb(n, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb) times instead of `n` times.
The other side of the story is that this class of approaches requires less memory as only two 1D array are considered at each iteration.

---

## Testing

For the suggested input:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': {'iris_0': 5.1, 'iris_1': 4.9, 'iris_2': 4.7, 'iris_3': 4.6, 'iris_4': 5.0, 'iris_5': 5.4, 'iris_6': 4.6, 'iris_7': 5.0, 'iris_8': 4.4, 'iris_9': 4.9, 'iris_10': 5.4, 'iris_11': 4.8, 'iris_12': 4.8, 'iris_13': 4.3, 'iris_14': 5.8, 'iris_15': 5.7, 'iris_16': 5.4, 'iris_17': 5.1, 'iris_18': 5.7, 'iris_19': 5.1, 'iris_20': 5.4, 'iris_21': 5.1, 'iris_22': 4.6, 'iris_23': 5.1, 'iris_24': 4.8, 'iris_25': 5.0, 'iris_26': 5.0, 'iris_27': 5.2, 'iris_28': 5.2, 'iris_29': 4.7, 'iris_30': 4.8, 'iris_31': 5.4, 'iris_32': 5.2, 'iris_33': 5.5, 'iris_34': 4.9, 'iris_35': 5.0, 'iris_36': 5.5, 'iris_37': 4.9, 'iris_38': 4.4, 'iris_39': 5.1, 'iris_40': 5.0, 'iris_41': 4.5, 'iris_42': 4.4, 'iris_43': 5.0, 'iris_44': 5.1, 'iris_45': 4.8, 'iris_46': 5.1, 'iris_47': 4.6, 'iris_48': 5.3, 'iris_49': 5.0, 'iris_50': 7.0, 'iris_51': 6.4, 'iris_52': 6.9, 'iris_53': 5.5, 'iris_54': 6.5, 'iris_55': 5.7, 'iris_56': 6.3, 'iris_57': 4.9, 'iris_58': 6.6, 'iris_59': 5.2, 'iris_60': 5.0, 'iris_61': 5.9, 'iris_62': 6.0, 'iris_63': 6.1, 'iris_64': 5.6, 'iris_65': 6.7, 'iris_66': 5.6, 'iris_67': 5.8, 'iris_68': 6.2, 'iris_69': 5.6, 'iris_70': 5.9, 'iris_71': 6.1, 'iris_72': 6.3, 'iris_73': 6.1, 'iris_74': 6.4, 'iris_75': 6.6, 'iris_76': 6.8, 'iris_77': 6.7, 'iris_78': 6.0, 'iris_79': 5.7, 'iris_80': 5.5, 'iris_81': 5.5, 'iris_82': 5.8, 'iris_83': 6.0, 'iris_84': 5.4, 'iris_85': 6.0, 'iris_86': 6.7, 'iris_87': 6.3, 'iris_88': 5.6, 'iris_89': 5.5, 'iris_90': 5.5, 'iris_91': 6.1, 'iris_92': 5.8, 'iris_93': 5.0, 'iris_94': 5.6, 'iris_95': 5.7, 'iris_96': 5.7, 'iris_97': 6.2, 'iris_98': 5.1, 'iris_99': 5.7, 'iris_100': 6.3, 'iris_101': 5.8, 'iris_102': 7.1, 'iris_103': 6.3, 'iris_104': 6.5, 'iris_105': 7.6, 'iris_106': 4.9, 'iris_107': 7.3, 'iris_108': 6.7, 'iris_109': 7.2, 'iris_110': 6.5, 'iris_111': 6.4, 'iris_112': 6.8, 'iris_113': 5.7, 'iris_114': 5.8, 'iris_115': 6.4, 'iris_116': 6.5, 'iris_117': 7.7, 'iris_118': 7.7, 'iris_119': 6.0, 'iris_120': 6.9, 'iris_121': 5.6, 'iris_122': 7.7, 'iris_123': 6.3, 'iris_124': 6.7, 'iris_125': 7.2, 'iris_126': 6.2, 'iris_127': 6.1, 'iris_128': 6.4, 'iris_129': 7.2, 'iris_130': 7.4, 'iris_131': 7.9, 'iris_132': 6.4, 'iris_133': 6.3, 'iris_134': 6.1, 'iris_135': 7.7, 'iris_136': 6.3, 'iris_137': 6.4, 'iris_138': 6.0, 'iris_139': 6.9, 'iris_140': 6.7, 'iris_141': 6.9, 'iris_142': 5.8, 'iris_143': 6.8, 'iris_144': 6.7, 'iris_145': 6.7, 'iris_146': 6.3, 'iris_147': 6.5, 'iris_148': 6.2, 'iris_149': 5.9}, 'sepal_width': {'iris_0': 3.5, 'iris_1': 3.0, 'iris_2': 3.2, 'iris_3': 3.1, 'iris_4': 3.6, 'iris_5': 3.9, 'iris_6': 3.4, 'iris_7': 3.4, 'iris_8': 2.9, 'iris_9': 3.1, 'iris_10': 3.7, 'iris_11': 3.4, 'iris_12': 3.0, 'iris_13': 3.0, 'iris_14': 4.0, 'iris_15': 4.4, 'iris_16': 3.9, 'iris_17': 3.5, 'iris_18': 3.8, 'iris_19': 3.8, 'iris_20': 3.4, 'iris_21': 3.7, 'iris_22': 3.6, 'iris_23': 3.3, 'iris_24': 3.4, 'iris_25': 3.0, 'iris_26': 3.4, 'iris_27': 3.5, 'iris_28': 3.4, 'iris_29': 3.2, 'iris_30': 3.1, 'iris_31': 3.4, 'iris_32': 4.1, 'iris_33': 4.2, 'iris_34': 3.1, 'iris_35': 3.2, 'iris_36': 3.5, 'iris_37': 3.6, 'iris_38': 3.0, 'iris_39': 3.4, 'iris_40': 3.5, 'iris_41': 2.3, 'iris_42': 3.2, 'iris_43': 3.5, 'iris_44': 3.8, 'iris_45': 3.0, 'iris_46': 3.8, 'iris_47': 3.2, 'iris_48': 3.7, 'iris_49': 3.3, 'iris_50': 3.2, 'iris_51': 3.2, 'iris_52': 3.1, 'iris_53': 2.3, 'iris_54': 2.8, 'iris_55': 2.8, 'iris_56': 3.3, 'iris_57': 2.4, 'iris_58': 2.9, 'iris_59': 2.7, 'iris_60': 2.0, 'iris_61': 3.0, 'iris_62': 2.2, 'iris_63': 2.9, 'iris_64': 2.9, 'iris_65': 3.1, 'iris_66': 3.0, 'iris_67': 2.7, 'iris_68': 2.2, 'iris_69': 2.5, 'iris_70': 3.2, 'iris_71': 2.8, 'iris_72': 2.5, 'iris_73': 2.8, 'iris_74': 2.9, 'iris_75': 3.0, 'iris_76': 2.8, 'iris_77': 3.0, 'iris_78': 2.9, 'iris_79': 2.6, 'iris_80': 2.4, 'iris_81': 2.4, 'iris_82': 2.7, 'iris_83': 2.7, 'iris_84': 3.0, 'iris_85': 3.4, 'iris_86': 3.1, 'iris_87': 2.3, 'iris_88': 3.0, 'iris_89': 2.5, 'iris_90': 2.6, 'iris_91': 3.0, 'iris_92': 2.6, 'iris_93': 2.3, 'iris_94': 2.7, 'iris_95': 3.0, 'iris_96': 2.9, 'iris_97': 2.9, 'iris_98': 2.5, 'iris_99': 2.8, 'iris_100': 3.3, 'iris_101': 2.7, 'iris_102': 3.0, 'iris_103': 2.9, 'iris_104': 3.0, 'iris_105': 3.0, 'iris_106': 2.5, 'iris_107': 2.9, 'iris_108': 2.5, 'iris_109': 3.6, 'iris_110': 3.2, 'iris_111': 2.7, 'iris_112': 3.0, 'iris_113': 2.5, 'iris_114': 2.8, 'iris_115': 3.2, 'iris_116': 3.0, 'iris_117': 3.8, 'iris_118': 2.6, 'iris_119': 2.2, 'iris_120': 3.2, 'iris_121': 2.8, 'iris_122': 2.8, 'iris_123': 2.7, 'iris_124': 3.3, 'iris_125': 3.2, 'iris_126': 2.8, 'iris_127': 3.0, 'iris_128': 2.8, 'iris_129': 3.0, 'iris_130': 2.8, 'iris_131': 3.8, 'iris_132': 2.8, 'iris_133': 2.8, 'iris_134': 2.6, 'iris_135': 3.0, 'iris_136': 3.4, 'iris_137': 3.1, 'iris_138': 3.0, 'iris_139': 3.1, 'iris_140': 3.1, 'iris_141': 3.1, 'iris_142': 2.7, 'iris_143': 3.2, 'iris_144': 3.3, 'iris_145': 3.0, 'iris_146': 2.5, 'iris_147': 3.0, 'iris_148': 3.4, 'iris_149': 3.0}, 'petal_length': {'iris_0': 1.4, 'iris_1': 1.4, 'iris_2': 1.3, 'iris_3': 1.5, 'iris_4': 1.4, 'iris_5': 1.7, 'iris_6': 1.4, 'iris_7': 1.5, 'iris_8': 1.4, 'iris_9': 1.5, 'iris_10': 1.5, 'iris_11': 1.6, 'iris_12': 1.4, 'iris_13': 1.1, 'iris_14': 1.2, 'iris_15': 1.5, 'iris_16': 1.3, 'iris_17': 1.4, 'iris_18': 1.7, 'iris_19': 1.5, 'iris_20': 1.7, 'iris_21': 1.5, 'iris_22': 1.0, 'iris_23': 1.7, 'iris_24': 1.9, 'iris_25': 1.6, 'iris_26': 1.6, 'iris_27': 1.5, 'iris_28': 1.4, 'iris_29': 1.6, 'iris_30': 1.6, 'iris_31': 1.5, 'iris_32': 1.5, 'iris_33': 1.4, 'iris_34': 1.5, 'iris_35': 1.2, 'iris_36': 1.3, 'iris_37': 1.4, 'iris_38': 1.3, 'iris_39': 1.5, 'iris_40': 1.3, 'iris_41': 1.3, 'iris_42': 1.3, 'iris_43': 1.6, 'iris_44': 1.9, 'iris_45': 1.4, 'iris_46': 1.6, 'iris_47': 1.4, 'iris_48': 1.5, 'iris_49': 1.4, 'iris_50': 4.7, 'iris_51': 4.5, 'iris_52': 4.9, 'iris_53': 4.0, 'iris_54': 4.6, 'iris_55': 4.5, 'iris_56': 4.7, 'iris_57': 3.3, 'iris_58': 4.6, 'iris_59': 3.9, 'iris_60': 3.5, 'iris_61': 4.2, 'iris_62': 4.0, 'iris_63': 4.7, 'iris_64': 3.6, 'iris_65': 4.4, 'iris_66': 4.5, 'iris_67': 4.1, 'iris_68': 4.5, 'iris_69': 3.9, 'iris_70': 4.8, 'iris_71': 4.0, 'iris_72': 4.9, 'iris_73': 4.7, 'iris_74': 4.3, 'iris_75': 4.4, 'iris_76': 4.8, 'iris_77': 5.0, 'iris_78': 4.5, 'iris_79': 3.5, 'iris_80': 3.8, 'iris_81': 3.7, 'iris_82': 3.9, 'iris_83': 5.1, 'iris_84': 4.5, 'iris_85': 4.5, 'iris_86': 4.7, 'iris_87': 4.4, 'iris_88': 4.1, 'iris_89': 4.0, 'iris_90': 4.4, 'iris_91': 4.6, 'iris_92': 4.0, 'iris_93': 3.3, 'iris_94': 4.2, 'iris_95': 4.2, 'iris_96': 4.2, 'iris_97': 4.3, 'iris_98': 3.0, 'iris_99': 4.1, 'iris_100': 6.0, 'iris_101': 5.1, 'iris_102': 5.9, 'iris_103': 5.6, 'iris_104': 5.8, 'iris_105': 6.6, 'iris_106': 4.5, 'iris_107': 6.3, 'iris_108': 5.8, 'iris_109': 6.1, 'iris_110': 5.1, 'iris_111': 5.3, 'iris_112': 5.5, 'iris_113': 5.0, 'iris_114': 5.1, 'iris_115': 5.3, 'iris_116': 5.5, 'iris_117': 6.7, 'iris_118': 6.9, 'iris_119': 5.0, 'iris_120': 5.7, 'iris_121': 4.9, 'iris_122': 6.7, 'iris_123': 4.9, 'iris_124': 5.7, 'iris_125': 6.0, 'iris_126': 4.8, 'iris_127': 4.9, 'iris_128': 5.6, 'iris_129': 5.8, 'iris_130': 6.1, 'iris_131': 6.4, 'iris_132': 5.6, 'iris_133': 5.1, 'iris_134': 5.6, 'iris_135': 6.1, 'iris_136': 5.6, 'iris_137': 5.5, 'iris_138': 4.8, 'iris_139': 5.4, 'iris_140': 5.6, 'iris_141': 5.1, 'iris_142': 5.1, 'iris_143': 5.9, 'iris_144': 5.7, 'iris_145': 5.2, 'iris_146': 5.0, 'iris_147': 5.2, 'iris_148': 5.4, 'iris_149': 5.1}, 'petal_width': {'iris_0': 0.2, 'iris_1': 0.2, 'iris_2': 0.2, 'iris_3': 0.2, 'iris_4': 0.2, 'iris_5': 0.4, 'iris_6': 0.3, 'iris_7': 0.2, 'iris_8': 0.2, 'iris_9': 0.1, 'iris_10': 0.2, 'iris_11': 0.2, 'iris_12': 0.1, 'iris_13': 0.1, 'iris_14': 0.2, 'iris_15': 0.4, 'iris_16': 0.4, 'iris_17': 0.3, 'iris_18': 0.3, 'iris_19': 0.3, 'iris_20': 0.2, 'iris_21': 0.4, 'iris_22': 0.2, 'iris_23': 0.5, 'iris_24': 0.2, 'iris_25': 0.2, 'iris_26': 0.4, 'iris_27': 0.2, 'iris_28': 0.2, 'iris_29': 0.2, 'iris_30': 0.2, 'iris_31': 0.4, 'iris_32': 0.1, 'iris_33': 0.2, 'iris_34': 0.2, 'iris_35': 0.2, 'iris_36': 0.2, 'iris_37': 0.1, 'iris_38': 0.2, 'iris_39': 0.2, 'iris_40': 0.3, 'iris_41': 0.3, 'iris_42': 0.2, 'iris_43': 0.6, 'iris_44': 0.4, 'iris_45': 0.3, 'iris_46': 0.2, 'iris_47': 0.2, 'iris_48': 0.2, 'iris_49': 0.2, 'iris_50': 1.4, 'iris_51': 1.5, 'iris_52': 1.5, 'iris_53': 1.3, 'iris_54': 1.5, 'iris_55': 1.3, 'iris_56': 1.6, 'iris_57': 1.0, 'iris_58': 1.3, 'iris_59': 1.4, 'iris_60': 1.0, 'iris_61': 1.5, 'iris_62': 1.0, 'iris_63': 1.4, 'iris_64': 1.3, 'iris_65': 1.4, 'iris_66': 1.5, 'iris_67': 1.0, 'iris_68': 1.5, 'iris_69': 1.1, 'iris_70': 1.8, 'iris_71': 1.3, 'iris_72': 1.5, 'iris_73': 1.2, 'iris_74': 1.3, 'iris_75': 1.4, 'iris_76': 1.4, 'iris_77': 1.7, 'iris_78': 1.5, 'iris_79': 1.0, 'iris_80': 1.1, 'iris_81': 1.0, 'iris_82': 1.2, 'iris_83': 1.6, 'iris_84': 1.5, 'iris_85': 1.6, 'iris_86': 1.5, 'iris_87': 1.3, 'iris_88': 1.3, 'iris_89': 1.3, 'iris_90': 1.2, 'iris_91': 1.4, 'iris_92': 1.2, 'iris_93': 1.0, 'iris_94': 1.3, 'iris_95': 1.2, 'iris_96': 1.3, 'iris_97': 1.3, 'iris_98': 1.1, 'iris_99': 1.3, 'iris_100': 2.5, 'iris_101': 1.9, 'iris_102': 2.1, 'iris_103': 1.8, 'iris_104': 2.2, 'iris_105': 2.1, 'iris_106': 1.7, 'iris_107': 1.8, 'iris_108': 1.8, 'iris_109': 2.5, 'iris_110': 2.0, 'iris_111': 1.9, 'iris_112': 2.1, 'iris_113': 2.0, 'iris_114': 2.4, 'iris_115': 2.3, 'iris_116': 1.8, 'iris_117': 2.2, 'iris_118': 2.3, 'iris_119': 1.5, 'iris_120': 2.3, 'iris_121': 2.0, 'iris_122': 2.0, 'iris_123': 1.8, 'iris_124': 2.1, 'iris_125': 1.8, 'iris_126': 1.8, 'iris_127': 1.8, 'iris_128': 2.1, 'iris_129': 1.6, 'iris_130': 1.9, 'iris_131': 2.0, 'iris_132': 2.2, 'iris_133': 1.5, 'iris_134': 1.4, 'iris_135': 2.3, 'iris_136': 2.4, 'iris_137': 1.8, 'iris_138': 1.8, 'iris_139': 2.1, 'iris_140': 2.4, 'iris_141': 2.3, 'iris_142': 1.9, 'iris_143': 2.3, 'iris_144': 2.5, 'iris_145': 2.3, 'iris_146': 1.9, 'iris_147': 2.0, 'iris_148': 2.3, 'iris_149': 1.8}})
```

we obtain:

```
print(np.all(np.isclose(biweight_midcorrelation_pd_OP(df), result)))
# True
print(np.all(np.isclose(corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_OP), result)))
# True
print(np.all(np.isclose(corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_np), result)))
# True
print(np.all(np.isclose(corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_npv), result)))
# True
print(np.all(np.isclose(corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_nb), result)))
# True
print(np.all(np.isclose(df.corr(method=pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_OP), result)))
# True
print(np.all(np.isclose(df.corr(method=pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_opt), result)))
# True
print(np.all(np.isclose(df.corr(method=pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_nb), result)))
# True
```

---

## Benchmarks

```
%timeit biweight_midcorrelation_pd_OP(df)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 22.1 ms per loop
%timeit corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_OP)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 682 µs per loop
%timeit corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_np)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 422 µs per loop
%timeit corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_npv)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 341 µs per loop
%timeit corr_np2pd(df, biweight_midcorrelation_nb)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 325 µs per loop
%timeit df.corr(method=pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_OP)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.96 ms per loop
%timeit df.corr(method=pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_opt)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.83 ms per loop
%timeit df.corr(method=pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_nb)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 506 µs per loop
```

These results would indicate the Numba-based approach to be the fastest, closely followed by the NumPy-vectorized version of your original approach.

Note that going from a Pandas-based computation to a pure NumPy-based approach (even with explicit looping) we get almost 30x speed factor.
And vectorizing the two `for` loops buys us another approx. 2x factor.

The `pd.DataFrame.corr()` based approach(es) are, when not using Numba, approx. 4x slower than your original approach rewritten in NumPy, so be careful even if you do not see explicit looping!
The Numba accelerated `pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_nb()` gives a significant boost to this family of approaches, but it cannot possibly avoid the overhead of the pre-computations.

Final warning: all these benchmarks should be taken with a grain of salt!

(**EDITED** to include a Numba-based approach to use with `pd.DataFrame.corr()`).

Comment: Wow, this answer is incredibly detailed and thorough.  Thank you so much for walking me through the various types of implementations.  Also I appreciate you reading into my "broadcasting" claim as actually "vectorizing".  I will change the question title based on this.  The numba one on my computer is much faster than than npv version for some reason but obviously both are faster than my original implementation.  I'm not very famiiliar with numba (now I will be) but I noticed there wasn't a numba implementation that takes (a,b).  Is that because numba optimizes populating the array?

Comment: @O.rka There was not a Numba-based pairwise computation because... I forgot to put one. In any case, this should be slower than the other family of approaches because a significant portion of the computation time is spent in the pre-computations (e.g. looping through the array for calculating medians), and thus it is more efficient to do this once and for all instead of doing it pairwise.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, very useful. In the `pairwise_biweight_midcorrelation_nb` implementation, should `return s_ab / np.sqrt(s_aa) / np.sqrt(s_bb)` not read `return s_ab / np.sqrt(s_aa) * np.sqrt(s_bb)`. Unless of course I'm missing something.

Comment: Should be: `s_ab / n(p.sqrt(s_aa) * np.sqrt(s_bb))` or, equivalently: `s_ab / np.sqrt(s_aa) / np.sqrt(s_bb)`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, you're exploiting the a/b/c and a/(bc) equivalence. I find the former difficult to read, personally. I thought you'd typo'd the operator, but I was neglecting operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

With a copy-n-paste of your `X`:

```
In [26]: X                                                                                     
Out[26]: 
          sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
iris_0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2
iris_1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2
iris_2             4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2
iris_3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2
iris_4             5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2
...                ...          ...           ...          ...
iris_145           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3
iris_146           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9
iris_147           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0
iris_148           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3
iris_149           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8

[150 rows x 4 columns]
```

and using it:

```
In [29]: X.corr(method=_biweight_midcorrelation)                                               
Out[29]: 
              sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
sepal_length      1.000000    -0.134780      0.831958     0.818575
sepal_width      -0.134780     1.000000     -0.430312    -0.374034
petal_length      0.831958    -0.430312      1.000000     0.952285
petal_width       0.818575    -0.374034      0.952285     1.000000
In [30]: X.corr?                                                                               
In [31]: _biweight_midcorrelation(X['sepal_length'],X['sepal_width'])                          
Out[31]: -0.13477989268659313
In [32]: _biweight_midcorrelation(X['sepal_length'],X['petal_length'])                         
Out[32]: 0.831958204443503
```

In `_biweight_midcorrelation(a, b)`, `a` and `b` are Series, the same size.  So all their derived arrays have the same shape, and `(a_item * b_item)` works just (by `broadcasting` - the rules of broadcasting apply to 2 1d arrays).  I don't see any need for 'outer products'.